# Avoid vim eating input after quit

Tags: vim

Some irritating issue when doing `git commit` (for example, there are other non-git scenarios): what I'd like to type (really fast):

```
git commit -a --amendEnter:wqEntergit push -fEnter
```

My problem is that after `:wqEnter` I have to wait until vim exits, and as I have a big vimrc it takes some time. I know, I'm spoiled.

I'm pretty sure there is a flag to git commit that will not open vim at all, but I'd prefer a more generic vim solution that will make vim not eat my input.

My vimrc is [here](https://github.com/devenv/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc)

Comment: Streamline your vimrc so it doesn't take a while to exit? What do you have in there that makes it take a noticeable amount of time to quit??

Comment: I try to keep it lean, but I do need lots of things, it's my main tool... https://github.com/devenv/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: Some time ~= 2 seconds, it still breaks the fluidity :)

Comment: Three possible culprits: plugins (especially all the bundle lines), whatever ncm2 is doing in that autocommand, and the initialize directories function call. I have some thoughts on possible answers i need to test out (basically different invocations of vim). Vim is my main tool too but doesnt have this problem even with extensive customization.

Comment: Nitpick: dont force push unless you really really have to (hint—you generally dont)

Comment: Yeah, I was going to profile it, pretty sure ncm is to blame, but it's the only one that handles python well, my problem is not with vim's speed though but with how it handles input on exit... And yeah, a forced push is a big no-no, but sometimes you just do :)

Comment: If you're all about saving time, then use `ZZ` to exit Vim instead of `:wq<CR>`, saves you two keystrokes and it's really quick to type... I see why you're curious about Vim leaving the keystrokes back to the shell, but I think that's hard to do since Vim switches terminal modes upon entering and exiting. You really want to make sure your Vim starts and exits quickly, so debug your Vimrc and potentially consider using a simpler Vimrc for git messages (you hardly need language support there.) Good luck!

Comment: The terminal mode explanation would win the best answer by me :) I guess the only way is to make it faster, which I did. After profiling switched from vundle to plug, removed isort and vim-notes, and switched from neotags to gutentags, now it opens/closes almost instantly. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Git

While the OP wants a vim-centric solution, I offer these git workarounds as
temporary band-aids (and useful information).

At the bottom, I provide resources for discovering the issue in vim.

### `no-edit` flag

Amending with the `--no-edit` flag causes vim not to launch (which is a good
idea if you do not need to edit the commit message: this is what the flag is
designed for).

### Use a "different" editor for commit messages

There are a couple of different configuration options here, and a couple of
different "vims" to try.

> See also `git(1)`, section `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES`, variable `GIT_EDITOR`.

#### One-off configuration

This is good for occasional usage (you can alias it, of course).

Use the `-c` flag on git:

```
git -c core.editor='vim variant' commit...
```

You could also set `GIT_EDITOR` via your shell (e.g., `env`, `export`, or
bash-isms).

#### Permanent configuration

This is good if you cannot resolve the vim issue and need it permanently.

Edit your configuration file (e.g., `git config --edit --global`), and add

```
[core]
    editor = vim variant
```

#### Vim variants

Vim's command line switches let us control various aspects of its behavior. You
might want to

- disable plugins (`--noplugin`)
- disable a vimrc (`-u NORC`)
- disable both (`-u NONE`)
- use a 'clean' vim (`--clean`)
- use a completely different vimrc for git (`-u DEFAULTS` or `-u ~/.mygitvimrc`)

The vimrc option allows us to craft an extremely efficient and minimal vimrc for
git work, while keeping our original for full-time stuff.

Experimentation may show that `-N` (not compatible mode) is necessary with some
of these.

Once you've chosen a setup that works, simply use `vim <args>...` as your git
editor, in one of the spots above.

## Vim

The first things to try on the vim side are [binary-split debugging your
vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and [profiling your
vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/182/cut-vim-load-time/189#189) to
find out what the root cause is.

It helps to be comfortable debugging for these steps. If you need to debug
vimscript, see `:help debug-scripts`.

Once you've identified the root cause, the next step is to squash it. You may
need to

- disable a plugin (possibly to be loaded on demand)
- change an autocommand to not be so nasty (look especially for autocommands
  that are accidentally triggered more than once such as those not in
  `augroup`)
- avoid expensive function calls in your vimrc
- help convert a heavy plugin to autoloads
- or a myriad of other performance-enhancing techniques.

As always, the key is to know where the problem lies first.

---

For OP, using pathogen and vundle together seems like a mistake (two different runtimepath/plugin managers?). Also, vundle provides [`vundle#begin` as a possible time-saver](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/9a38216a1c0c597f978d73547d37681fc689c90d/autoload/vundle.vim#L70) over `vundle#rc`.

Comment: Yeah, `--no-edit` is what I assumed that exists in git :) I was wondering though if there is a solution for vim other than 'make it faster', partially out of curiosity, something that will tell it to pass input forth once it realizes that it needs to exit... Thanks for the pathogen catch, wasn't aware it's still there, and for the vundle tips :)

Comment: you may be able to load ncm2 more optionally to speed things up. But definitely go with a debug/profile to make sure.